# What Linux software component handles display detection and monitor arrangement

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, x11

I am working on a multiple display system running Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia graphics card.
Currently all connected displays (not just the added/removed display) turn black momentarily after the connection/disconnection of a display.
I would like to change this behavior so that connected displays wont be affected by the change.
There are a few components I am aware of that are involved in the display process: Kernel, X.org server, Desktop manager, Windows manager.
Which one of these (or other components not listed) is responsible for blackening all the displays before rearranging them and restoring the image?

Comment: That is a driver issue, so in the closed source components.